# Bubble sort algorithm in Java

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, sorting

I have a problem with my bubble sort algorithm. I've tried to find the solution but i cant just solve my problem.

this is the sorting part of the code

```
    for (int i = values.length - 1; i > 1; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (values[j] > values[(j + 1)]) {
                int temp = values[i];
                values[i] = values[j];
                values[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

EDIT: Here is the working code

```
    for (int i = values.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++) {
            if (values[j] > values[(j + 1)]) {  //Check if sort is needed
                int temp = values[j];
                values[j] = values[j+1];
                values[j+1] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: And the problem is? Have you tried debugging it?

Comment: The problem was that it didnt sort it correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should be switching items `j` and `j+1` not `j` and `i`. Notice that you compared `values[j] > values[j+1]` but switched `values[j]` with `values[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You're swapping different indexes then the ones you compare. I think you're error would be solved by changing the following lines:

```
int temp = values[j+1];
values[j+1] = values[j];
values[j] = temp
```